# Is there a phrase commonly used to describe a day off that happens accidentally?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Is there a phrase that is often used when someone unexpectedly finds themselves free from work or other obligations due to circumstances beyond their control?

Comment: Do you mean like a plumber who finds themself without a job on some day. For most sole traders that would be "a day to finally try to get up to date with paperwork".

Comment: @JamesK Great! But, how about an office worker? Would that expression fit too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office workers normally don't get to go home just because there is no work.  I'd call this "a quiet day in the office".  Office workers would expect to continue to be paid even if their company doesn't provide them with any duties on a particular day.

Sole traders, such a plumbers or other people who run their own business, or are part of the "gig economy" might have days without work. This is normally a problem, as if they don't get work, they don't get paid. Sole traders might use such a day to catch up with the paperwork of running a business.  Gig workers are probably online, looking for the next job.  These kind of workers don't really get a "day off".

Comment: Thank you, James!